# Remove sort icon in Format as Table

Tags: excel, vba

I used "Format as Table" There are sort icons at the top for every column. How do I remove the sort icon from some of the rows and keep the remaining?

Comment: I hope I'm wrong, but I don't think it is possible. And did you mean "remove the sort icon from some of the **columns**"?

Comment: @Kapol - Its possible. See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can remove ALL the sort buttons (workaround)

1- Select the data range

2- Format as table

3- Right click --> Select `Table` --> `Convert to Range`

This will keep the formatting, but the sort buttons would be removed.

**Alternatively**, if you want to keep some of the sort icons, then you have to use VBA

1- Suppose this is your formatted table

[image]

2- Write this function

```
Sub RemoveSortArrows()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each col In Range("A1:J1")
        If Not (col.Column = 1 Or col.Column = 4) Then
            col.AutoFilter Field:=col.Column, Visibledropdown:=False
        End If
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

3- This should be the result

[image]

Comment: The non-VBA way you preserve only formatting and lose all other functionality of tables, like automatic formula filling. So I don't think that's the desired result. As for the VBA solution, props to you :)

Comment: @Yeah ... but wanted to present both options as the user might only need to format the data in a particular style and not really care about the sort (you can sort it anyways using `Data->Sort`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add one thing to **Pankaj's** answer. Instead of hard typing the header range, you can use

```
Dim myTable As ListObject

Set myTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects([the name of your table goes in here])
```

And in the `For` loop signature you type

```
For Each Cell In myTable.HeaderRowRange
```